# ADO.NET background pool validation

Tags: ado.net

in Java, application servers like JBoss EAP have the option to periodically verify the connections in a database pool (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/sect-database_connection_validation). This has been very useful for removing stale connections.

I'm now looking at a ADO.NET application, and I was wondering if there was any similar functionality that could be used with a Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up find [this post](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/improving-the-quality-of-sql-server-database-connections-in-the-cloud/) by redgate that describes some of the validation that goes on when connections are taken from the pool:

> If the connection has died because a router has decided that it no
>   longer wants to forward your packets and no other routers like you
>   either then there is no way to know this unless you try to send some
>   data and don’t get a response.
>
> If you create a connection and a connection pool is created and
>   connections are put into the pool and not used, the longer they are in
>   there, the bigger the chance of something bad happening to it.
>
> When you go to use a connection there is nothing to warn you that a
>   router has stopped forwarding your packets until you go to use it; so
>   until you use it, you do not know that there is a problem.
>
> This was an issue with connection pooling that was fixed in the first
>   .Net 4 reliability update (see issue 14 which vaguely describes this)
>   with a feature called “Connection Pool Resiliency”. The update meant
>   that when a connection is about to be taken from the pool, it is
>   checked for TCP validity and only returned if it is in a good state.